# Bulk renaming of csv files of same name using shell script

Tags: shell, csv, rename

I have aboout 100 .csv files with the same name in different sub directories. I need to copy all the data in these files into a single csv file but since they all have the same name they over write on each other. Can you please help me with the shell script code where i can rename all these files in order like say for example: 
All my files are in the name example.csv in different subfolders.
I want them to be example1.csv in subfolder1, example2.csv in subfolder2 and so on...

This is the script that would over write on the csv files.

```
for c in *.csv
do
echo $c
cat $c >> fullreport.csv
done
```

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it this way instead:

```
for c in *.csv
do
    echo "$c"
    cat "$c"
done > fullreport.csv
```

Assuming `fullreport.csv` still doesn't exist. Delete it if needed.

To add more directories, just specify them space after space:

```
for c in *.csv a/*.csv b/*.csv
do
    echo "$c"
    cat "$c"
done > fullreport.csv
```

If you want to do it recursively, use `find` like:

```
while read c; do
    echo "$c"
    cat "$c"
done < <(find -type f -iname '*.csv') > fullreport.csv
```

You can place your output as well on a different directory instead to prevent conflicts like `> ../fullreport.csv`.

Answer (score 1):

"I need to copy all the data in these files into a single csv file..."

```
cat */example.csv > fullreport.csv
```